# Does this condition on an uncountable collection of open sets have a name?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{U_\alpha: \alpha \in \omega_1\}$ be any collection of open sets of $X$.

> **The condition is this:** if $\bigcap U_\alpha\not= \emptyset$, then $\bigcap U_\alpha$ is closed.

Does this condition on an uncountable collection of open sets have a name?

If I ask more, which topological property could imply this condition?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you require $\{ U_{\alpha} \}$ to all be distinct?

Comment: Note that the condition $\bigcap U_\alpha \neq \emptyset$ is unnecessary, since the empty set is always closed.

Comment: @andrewsalmon, i think thats implicit. Otherwise, the condition asserts that every open set is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement of the result and the proof have been corrected (I hope).

**Theorem.** If $X$ is a $T_1$ space with this property, then either $X$ has no infinite subset that is the intersection of $\omega_1$ distinct open sets, or $X$ is has the discrete topology. In particular, $X$ is discrete if $|X|\ge\omega_1$.

**Proof.** Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space with this property. Suppose that $\mathscr{U}=\{U_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ is a family of distinct open sets with infinite intersection $A$. Let $F$ be any finite subset of $A$; then $U_\xi\setminus F$ is open for each $\xi<\omega_1$, so $A\setminus F=\bigcap_{\xi<\omega_1}(U_\xi\setminus F)$ is closed. Thus, $F$ is open in the relative topology on $A$, which must therefore be discrete.

Now let $W=X\setminus A$. Let $\{A_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$ be a family of distinct subsets of $A$ with empty intersection, for $\xi<\omega_1$ let $V_\xi=A_\xi\cup W$, and let $\mathscr{V}=\{V_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$; $\mathscr{V}$ is a family of $\omega_1$ distinct open sets, so $W=\bigcap\mathscr{V}$ is closed, and $A$ and $W$ are clopen in $X$.

Finally, let $U$ be any open subset of $W$. The argument of the preceding paragraph can be applied to $\{A_\xi\cup U:\xi<\omega_1\}$ to show that $U$ is closed in $X$. Thus, every open subset of $W$ is clopen, $W$ has the discrete topology, and hence so has $X$. $\dashv$

A countably infinite set with the cofinite topology is an example of a non-discrete $T_1$ space with the property.

Comment: How do you know that all $U_\xi\cup V$ are distinct?

Comment: @Stefan: Oops. Of course they’re not: they’re all equal to $X\setminus\{x\}$. I’ll have to think about it a bit to see what can be salvaged.